# Generate valid combinations of numbers in array of digits

Tags: javascript, combinations, combinatorics

I’m trying to generate all valid combinations of numbers from an array of digits. Let’s assume we have the following:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 9, 4, 7];
```

We need to output something like this:

```
1 2 9 4 7
1 2 9 47
1 2 94 7
1 2 947
1 29 4 7
1 29 47
1 294 7
1 2947
12 9 4 7
12 9 47
12 94 7
12 947
129 4 7
129 47
1294 7
12947
```

An invalid number would be 91, 497, 72 and so on.

I tried this but I’m not satisfied with the result:

```js
const combination = (arr) => {

  let i, j, temp;
  let result = [];
  let arrLen = arr.length;
  let power = Math.pow;
  let combinations = power(2, arrLen);

  for (i = 0; i < combinations; i += 1) {
    temp = '';

    for (j = 0; j < arrLen; j++) {
      if ((i & power(2, j))) {
        temp += arr[j];
      }
    }
    result.push(temp);
  }
  return result;
}

const result = combination([1, 2, 9, 4, 7]);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not satisfied ? You need to specify problem or error you are getting.

Comment: What's the problem you are seeking to solve with this question?

Comment: checkout https://github.com/dankogai/js-combinatorics -  you may find suitable metod for permutations

Comment: @Xufox your code works exactly as I wanted.Thanks. But it's hard to understand how it works.

Comment: @AlexandarTargov I’ve explained it in an answer.

Answer (score 4):

This code does what you want:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 9, 4, 7],
  result = Array.from({length: 2 ** (arr.length - 1)}, (_, index) => index.toString(2).padStart(arr.length - 1, "0"))
    .map((binary) => JSON.parse("[" + arr.map((num, position) => num + (Number(binary[position]) ? "," : "")).join("") + "]"));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

It results in:

```
[
  [12947],
  [1294, 7],
  [129, 47],
  [129, 4, 7],
  [12, 947],
  [12, 94, 7],
  [12, 9, 47],
  [12, 9, 4, 7],
  [1, 2947],
  [1, 294, 7],
  [1, 29, 47],
  [1, 29, 4, 7],
  [1, 2, 947],
  [1, 2, 94, 7],
  [1, 2, 9, 47],
  [1, 2, 9, 4, 7]
]
```

---

Assuming, the expected result does not depend on order, the spaces represent a binary pattern:

```
12947     => 0000
1294 7    => 0001
129 47    => 0010
…
1 29 47   => 1010
…
1 2 9 4 7 => 1111
```

---

We can utilize this pattern with a counter that we convert to a binary string. We also pad that string with `0` so it always remains 4 digits long:

```
index.toString(2).padStart(arr.length - 1, "0")
```

For *n* digits in `arr`, there are exactly 2<sup>*n* - 1</sup> combinations, so we use:

```
{length: 2 ** (arr.length - 1)}
```

This is an object that has a `length` property of 2<sup>`arr.length` - 1</sup>.

We combine both those things into an [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) call which accepts two arguments:

- an object to turn into an array
- a function for mapping each slot

Turning an object with a `length` property into an array means that we create an array with `length` many slots.

The mapping function accepts the index of a slot as the second parameter. We only use the index — as a counter for our binary number.

So, finally this whole expression:

```
Array.from({length: 2 ** (arr.length - 1)}, (_, index) => index.toString(2).padStart(arr.length - 1, "0"))
```

evaluates to the following array:

```
[
  "0000",
  "0001",
  "0010",
  "0011",
  "0100",
  "0101",
  "0110",
  "0111",
  "1000",
  "1001",
  "1010",
  "1011",
  "1100",
  "1101",
  "1110",
  "1111"
]
```

---

We need to further map this to the final result:

```
.map((binary) => …)
```

For each array element, `binary` is one of the binary strings from the array above.

In order to turn e.g. `"0110"` into something like `"12,9,47"`, we need to `map` over `arr` as well. Every digit `num` from `arr` should be followed by `,` at `position`, iff `binary` is `1` at `position`:

```
arr.map((num, position) => num + (Number(binary[position]) ? "," : "")).join("")
```

The expression `(Number(binary[position]) ? "," : "")` evaluates `binary` at the specified position as a number. If it’s *truthy*, i.e. anything but `0`, it evaluates to `","`, if it’s *falsy*, i.e. `0`, it evaluates to `""`.

So an intermediate array would look like `["1", "2,", "9,", "4", "7"]`. All of this is joined together to `"12,9,47"`.

Then, with `JSON.parse("[" +` … `+ "]")` it’s being treated and parsed as an array, so it turns into `[12, 9, 47]`. Since these steps are applied for each binary string, you’ll end up with the final result.

---

- `2 ** (arr.length - 1)` can be replaced by `Math.pow(2, arr.length - 1)` if ECMAScript 7 is not supported.
- `{length: 2 ** (arr.length - 1)}` can be replaced by `new Array(2 ** (arr.length - 1))`.
- `(Number(binary[position]) ? "," : "")` can be replaced by `["", ","][Number(binary[position])]`. In this case the evaluated number will be used as an index for a temporary array.

Comment: Amazing Bro , I am glad to see this answer :) description for binary pattern position

Comment: All this time, the exponentiation was the wrong way around… fixed it now… I hope.

Answer (score 3):

So you need to iterate over all the combinations of "space" and "not space" between all the numbers. With `n` items, there will be `n - 1` spaces, and `2 ** (n - 1)` different lists.

So you could do something like this to get all the possible lists:

```js
const combination = arr => {
    const len = arr.length;
    const n = Math.pow(2, len - 1);
    const combinations = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        let this_combination = [arr[0]];
        for (let j = 1; j < len; j++) {
           if (i & Math.pow(2, j - 1)) {
               // If the jth bit is on, no space. Append to the last element.
               const last_index = this_combination.length - 1;
               this_combination[last_index] = +(this_combination[last_index] + '' + arr[j]);
           } else {
               // Otherwise create a new list item.
               this_combination.push(arr[j]);
           }
        }
        // Consider making this function a generator and making this a yield.
        combinations.push(this_combination);
    }
    return combinations;
}

const result = combination([1, 2, 9, 4, 7]);
console.log(result.map(line => line.join(' ')).join('\n'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you wanted each individual item seperately, for each item in the array, combine it with no other item, then just the next item, then the next 2 items, etc. untill the end:

```js
const combination = arr => {
    const len = arr.length;
    const combinations = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        let item = arr[i];
        combinations.push(item);
        for (let j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            item = +(item + '' + arr[j]);
            combinations.push(item);
        }
    }
    return combinations;
}

const result = combination([1, 2, 9, 4, 7]);
console.log(result.join('\n'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach by iterating the array and insert a space or not and fork the calling of the same function with an incremented index.

```js
function combine(array) {
    function fork(i, p) {
        if (i === array.length) {
            result.push(p);
            return;
        }
        fork(i + 1, p + ' ' + array[i]);
        fork(i + 1, p + array[i]);
    }
    var result = [];
    fork(1, array[0].toString());
    return result;
}

console.log(combine([1, 2, 9, 4, 7]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using below code where 3 pointer is used,

1. 1st pointer print 0th position to cursor position.
2. 2nd pointer print cursor to diffidence position in each iteration .
3. 3rd pointer print cursor position to last position.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 9, 4, 7];
console.log(arr.join(','));
for(let diff=2;diff<=arr.length;diff++){
  for(i=0,j=diff;arr.length>=i+diff;j++,i++){
    var temp = [];
    if(i>0)
      temp.push(arr.slice(0,i).join(','));
    temp.push(arr.slice(i,j).join(''));
    if(j<arr.length)
      temp.push(arr.slice(j,arr.length).join(','));
    console.log(temp.join(','));
  }
}
```